# support for kmod-hpsa-3.4.20-191 deb package in ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, package-management, hp

unlike in centos which has kmod-hpsa-3.4.20-191.rhel7u8.x86_64.rpm, I'm looking for deb files for the same package, kmod-hpsa when extracted has hpsa.ko

I tried a couple of the below links:

1. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man4/hpsa.4.html - not of much use, its all man pages
2. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/allpackages - didn't find the package listed here
3. https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/spp-gen9/2020.03.0_supspp_rhel7.8_x86_64/ - HPE lists very well for RPMs not able to get the exact file for ubuntu here.
4. https://sourceforge.net/projects/cciss/files/hpsa-3.0-tarballs/ - one gets the tarball of source code and has lots of compilation errors to fix.

Is there any deb file for kmod-hpsa when extracted should be able to get the hpsa.ko file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any `kmod-hpsa` because `hpsa` module is already included in Ubuntu 22.04.

You can check it by

```
modinfo hpsa
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with what I was looking for.